# Clear a text_field after create w/o refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Right now I'm using AJAX for creating comments. However when I hit enter the textfield remains populated. I want the field to refresh (and still be able to write in another comment). no errors but it still doesn't refresh the textfield it seems. The create part works fine.

create.js/erb: (need to fix the second line here so that it fully replaces)

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@micropost) %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @micropost.comments))%>")
$("#comment_field_<%=@micropost.id%>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: @micropost) %>")
```

Microposts/_micropost:

```
<span id="<%= dom_id(micropost) %>"><%= render micropost.comments %></span>
<span id="comment_field_<%=micropost.id%>"><%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost if signed_in? %></span>
```

Shared/Comment_form:

```
<%= form_for @comment, id:"comment_form", remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :micropost_id, micropost.id %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= link_to gravatar_for((current_user), size: 29) %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something...", id: "comment_text_field", :style => "width: 508px; text-indent: 5px" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please post the controller action and contents of 'shared/comment_form' too.

Comment: I originally wrote it because i couldn't accept my answer yet and i didnt want to waste people's time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to only use jquery to clear the text_field by setting empty value

create.js.erb

```
$("#comment_text_field_<%=@micropost.id%>").val("")
```

best practice to use a unique dynamic ID but probably would have worked either way.

Shared/Comment_form:

```
 <%= f.text_field :content, id: "comment_text_field_#{micropost.id}" %>
```